# Definition of quotient manifolds, and $\Gamma \backslash \mathscr H$ as a quotient manifold

Tags: modular-forms, complex-manifolds

I have just encountered some subtlety with quotient manifolds and now I don't think I understand some things as well as I thought I did.

Let $X$ be a real or complex analytic manifold, and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$.  Let $p: X \rightarrow X/\sim$ be the quotient map.  Here are two possible definitions of *quotient manifold*.

- A manifold structure on $X/\sim$, such that $g \mapsto g \circ p$ defines a bijection

$$\operatorname{Hom}(X/\sim, Y) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$$

where the morphisms are taken in the appropriate category (either real or complex manifolds).

- A manifold structure on $X/\sim$ such that $p$ is a submersion.

Are these definitions equivalent?  I believe that the second definition implies the first.

Let $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.  It is possible to put a complex manifold structure on the quotient space $\Gamma \backslash \mathscr H$, such that the map $p: \mathscr H \rightarrow \Gamma \backslash \mathscr H$ is (complex) analytic.  However, this map is not a submersion.  If $\tau \in \mathscr H$ is an elliptic point, and $h \geq 2$ is the order of the image of the stabilizer of $\tau$ in $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then locally near $\tau$, $p$ looks like the map $z \mapsto z^h$ near $0$, whose derivative vanishes.

In what sense, if any, can $\Gamma \backslash \mathscr H$ be thought of as a quotient of manifolds?

Comment: The exact structure of $\Gamma\H$ is something called orbifold (because of the torsion elements in your lattice). Nevertheless, Selberg's lemma tell you that in most cases of interest (say f.g. linear group over field of char 0), you can just move to a deeper congruence and remove the torsion (in other word, in many cases, lattices are virtually torsion free).

Answer (score 3):

As is often the case, a slight recasting of the question may produce a much-easier-to-answer question which suffices for the actual purposes at hand.

As in the comment and in the original question, already for quotients of the upper half-plane, and all the more so for quotients of classical domains $G/K$ for higher-$\mathbb R$-rank Lie groups and maximal compacts $K$, the natural quotient structure at least *appears* to give the quotient singularities.

It is of course interesting to try to understand various desingularization possibilities... but this is a difficult issue, I think.

In contrast, for elementary reasons $\Gamma\backslash G$ is *always* a smooth manifold, so $C^\infty_c(\Gamma\backslash G)$ immediately makes sense. And, then, instead of trying to define $C^\infty_c(\Gamma\backslash G/K)$ directly in terms of some (not reliably existent!) smooth structure on $\Gamma\backslash G/K$, for many purposes it suffices to consider the right $K$-fixed functions $C^\infty_c(\Gamma\backslash G)^K$ in $C^\infty(\Gamma\backslash G)$...